# Find Enum Types inside a model class

Tags: c#, enums

I have a model class that have enum types, ints,strings e.t.c..

For Example;

```
    public class CustomerModel
{

    public int id { get; set; }
    public CustomerType CustomerType { get; set; }
    public DateTime MembershipStartDate { get; set; }
    public CustomerClass CustomerClass { get; set; }       
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public EducationStatus EducationStatus { get; set; }
    public Gender Gender { get; set; }
    public int NationalityId { get; set; }

}
```

I need to catch enum types and their names from this model class. I tried GetType , GetTypes , GetProperty e.t.c but couldn't find any solution. If i can catch that enum types, i can use that types everywhere in my app easily. Otherwise i need to catch them by one by.please help.

Comment: Can you share whatever you tried and explain what issue you are facing in that?

Comment: @Chetan Ranpariya I have a xamarin app that pull enum values from webAPI. Like i send my enum name to webAPI and get back the values. I want to catch and send enum names with their property name not like a string that i wrote inside my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
Type type = typeof(YourClass);
var properties = type.GetProperties();
var propertiesWithEnumTypes = properties.Where(x => x.PropertyType.IsEnum);
var typeNames = propertiesWithEnumTypes.Select(x => x.PropertyType.Name);
```

It's very straightforward: get the `Type` instance of your class, get its properties, filter the list of properties to only keep those whose property type is enum, map the filtered list to the types' names.

If you want to get the property's name instead of the enum type's name, replace `x.PropertyType.Name` with `x.Name`;